# Atomic swap solidity library

Tags: solidity, evm, library, cross-chain

Is there a production-ready atomic swap library to be used in solidity?
This would be needed to implement the EVM part of an atomic swap protocol

Answer (score 1):

Not really (till i know). What you need to do is learn how to perform a swap according to the protocol you want to use (curve, uniswap, uniswapV2, uniswapV3) and do everything in the same solidity function, make sure that there's profit in the end of the transaction to avoid losing money.

Here is an example of atomic swap within UniswapV2 x UniswapV2:

```
function arbitrage(address routerA, address routerB, address token) external onlyOwner returns(bool){

        address[] memory path2 = new address[](2);
        path2[0] = WETH;
        path2[1] = token;

        address cttAddress = address(this);

        uint amount = IERC20(WETH).balanceOf(cttAddress);
        IERC20(WETH).approve(routerA, amount);

        IUniswapV2Router02(routerA).swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
            amount, 
            0, 
            path2, 
            cttAddress, 
            block.timestamp + 1200
        );      

        uint tokenBalance = IERC20(token).balanceOf(cttAddress);
        IERC20(token).approve(routerB, tokenBalance);

        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = token;
        path[1] = WETH;

        IUniswapV2Router02(routerB).swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
            tokenBalance, 
            0, 
            path, 
            cttAddress, 
            block.timestamp + 1200
        );

        uint finalBalance = IERC20(WETH).balanceOf(cttAddress);
        require(finalBalance >= amount, "No profit");
        return true;
    }
```